# UIAlertController TextField BorderStyle, IOS

Tags: c#, ios, uialertcontroller, uitextborderstyle

i created a UIAlertController and within the AlertController i added a UITextfield, and i want it without any kind of borders around. 
There is an image below with the borders, and i would like to delete that square border.

[image]

I would like to end up with a non-border TextField, and the only thing you could see is the text you are typing. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: I am against "-1" without a comment. +1

Comment: Did u solve the problem?

Comment: Not yet, i tried the same code you post, and didn't work i don't understand why isn't working so the borders keep appearing

Answer (score 0):

On the part that u add the textfield, u can set its properties.

```
alert.addTextField { (textField) in
      textField.placeholder     = "Bla sheep"
      textField.borderStyle     = .none   //remove borders
      textField.backgroundColor = .clear  //transparent background
}
```